# Error while connecting to SQL Server 20014

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99Zus.png)

I spent lot of time to resolve this i also enable TCP/IP service but still facing same error

Answer (score 0):

There are many things could cause your issue.
1 common is your services is not started. Open Services.msc in your Database's server, find the services `SQL Server ("your-server-name-instance")` and check whether it's running or not

Also, just check the firewalls if you are connecting from different machine